# No puedo enviar contenido con el Google Cast SDK a mi smart tv (Error: Media no seleccionada)

Tags: java, android, google-api, cast

Aqui esta el listener de la sessionmager el cual permite manejar el estado de la sesion. Para mi que todo esta bien pero no se que es lo q esta pasando

```
//Listener    
private void setupCastListener(){
    mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>() {


        @Override
        public void onSessionStarted(CastSession castSession, String s) {
            onAplicationConnected(castSession);
        }

//Demas metodos....
        private void onAplicationConnected(CastSession castSession){

            mcastSession = castSession;
            if(!util.getUrl().equals("")){
                //VideoPlayer
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Url ha mostrar " + util.getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadRemoteMedia();
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Se ha conectado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "La url no pudo ser leida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        private void onAplicationDisconnected(){
            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "El dispositivo se ha desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    };

}

private void loadRemoteMedia() {
    //Cargar datos
    try {
        if (mcastSession == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No hay ningun dispositivo conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = mcastSession.getRemoteMediaClient();

        if (remoteMediaClient == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No hay MediaClient ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        remoteMediaClient.load(buildMediaInfo(),
                new MediaLoadOptions.Builder()
                        .setAutoplay(true)
                        .setPlayPosition(0).build());

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Load Remote Media is configured bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {

    MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE,"Dragon Ball");

    return new MediaInfo.Builder(util.getUrl())
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType("videos/mp4")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .build();
}
```

Ahi envio la url para que sea cargada. Pero en la app me dice que no se ha selecionado ningun archivo para reproducir. Lo que no me parece logico ya que le estoy enviando la url para que la cargue.He intendo con varias pruebas pero no sale

Comment: Porque no usas el MediaController en lugar del MediaMetadata es la que uso yo y no he tenido problemas

Comment: Ok gracias por contestar. Lo probare